# Cypher Neo4j summation in relationship node up to 2 layer

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to work this line of query in Neo4j cypher?

Match (c:Client)-[t:TRANSFER*..2]-(p:Partner)
Return sum(toInteger((t.records))

It shows syntax error when I run this line of code.

However, below the line of code able to run if I did not specified how many path to return,

**Match (c:Client)-[t:TRANSFER]-(p:Partner)
Return sum(toInteger((t.records))**

Comment: @Graphileon
I have tried alternative way, but it doesn't return the ideal output. Whereby I have first identify to return 2 layer path 
Match (c : Client)-[:TRANSFER*..2]-(p:Partner) 
Match (c)-[t:TRANSFER]-(p) Return sum(toInteger((t.records)) 
Return sum(toInteger((t.records))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this

```
MATCH path = (c:Client)-[:TRANSFER*..2]-(p:Partner) 

UNWIND relationships(path) AS r

RETURN sum(toInteger(r.records))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!
I have tried alternative way, but it doesn't return the ideal output.
Whereby I have first identify to return 2 layer path

Match (c : Client)-[:TRANSFER*..2]-(p:Partner)
Match (c)-[t:TRANSFER]-(p)
Return sum(toInteger((t.records))